# Power BI Connection to On-Premise SQL Server Without Data Gateway

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

Is it possible to use Power BI Services to connect to an on-premise SQL Server without a Data Gateway?

I could open up the firewall, even though I know it's not recommended.

I just want to know if it is possible or not and the reason why.

Comment: Given `Import Data from SQL Server` is the second of the 3 options when you add a data source in Power BI Desktop, what are you actually asking? How to import local data into the Azure-hosted Power BI Services? How to publish a dataset with already loaded files? The Data Gateway is needed if you want to refresh an Azure-hosted dataset using local data. You can't avoid it, whether it's the Personal edition used with your personal dashboards or the Enterprise version that works with workspaces

Comment: `it's not recommended` not just that, it's probably impossible. First of all Power BI services won't try to connect to arbitrary servers over the public internet. Second your own ISP may be blocking SQL Server's ports, because only companies really need those ports. And when they do, they use VPNs.

Comment: Technically there's no reason it _wouldn't_ work as long as your on premise SQL is set up to have a public adress (via NAT) and required ports are all open.